# Highchart show results without comma for individual line

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

Hi there I would like to draw a chart with a three lines in Highchart. Two of them can shows results as shown in the data [4.12,3.34,5.45] / [3.45,5.45,3.23] but the third line should be visibe without any comma. Resuls should be like [7,4,2]

code:

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: '',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    colors: ['blue', 'red'],
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        lineWidth: 3
      },
      tooltip: {
        hideDelay: 200
      }
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: '',
      x: -20
    },
       xAxis: {
        categories: [
            ''
        ]
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
   tooltip: {
       pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.0f} h</b><br/>',

      valueSuffix: ' h',
      crosshairs: true,
      shared: true
      },

    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 1
    },
     plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2);
                        }
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: true
                }
            },
    series: [{
      name: '1',
      color: 'rgba(51, 204, 204, 0.75)',
      lineWidth: 2,
      data: [4.12,3.34,5.45]
    }, {
      name: '2',
      color: 'rgba(255, 77, 77,0.75)',
      marker: {
        radius: 6
      },
        data: [3.45,5.45,3.23]
    },{
      name: '3',
      color:'#bfbfbf',
      marker: {
        radius: 6
      },
        data: [7.34,4.23,1.78]
    }]
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmv5e8v7/3/
Can you guys help in this?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @BarbaraLaird wrote, you can also define format of data labels for only one series, like this:

```
dataLabels: {
    format: '{y:.0f}'
}
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.format

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ozvgfkj0/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional to your `dataLabels` `formatter` function:

```
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.series.name == '3')
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
        else
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
      }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/bmv5e8v7/4/

Comment: Amazingly :) Thanks a lot.